# CSS stylesheet appears blank on console

Tags: html, css

(first time here!) I'm reaching out for help because, as the title says, my stylesheet appears blank on the chrome console, but the same stylesheet has the code when I access the server where it is located.

For some context, It is located on a remote server where the website to which the stylesheet is applied, and I edit it via EMACS, and so far it looks fine, but when I open the stylesheet on the developer tools in chrome the stylesheet appears blank.

Here's the code as it appears on the stylesheet:

Name: styles.css

```
body, main{
    display: flex;
}

body{
    flex-direction: column;
}

main{
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: auto;
}

article{
    flex: 1;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

aside{
    flex: 2;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

And here it is adressed in the head of the html:

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
```

I'm new to this, so I am completely lost as to how something that is being referenced on the html shows blank when I load the website. Feel free to ask me if you don't understand something.

**EDIT**

A bit of clarification: I used Apache to create the website, and the css file is located on the same directory as the html file.

**EDIT 2**

Problem was with my computer's cache, so problem solved!

Comment: Is the file cached?

Comment: No, it is located on a remote server.

Comment: What epascarello means is that your browser might be showing you a different version of your HTML file that what you have on the server. Have you cleared your browser's cache? Have you checked the browser's developer tools for errors?

Comment: try href="./styles.css"

Comment: Do your styles get applied even though you can't see them in the style editor?

Comment: Thank you j08691! I should have known, since I always have problems with my computer's memory...